# GLTF loaded object drag and drop using three js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, three.js

I tried to load the gltf (object) which is made up of multiple elements when I try to select and drag the object, I am able to drag only one element. Please help me to fix this issue.

```js
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load(‘W3030 / W3030.gltf’, (gltf) => {
  this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
  gltf.scene.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
  gltf.scene.traverse(function(object) {
    if (object.isMesh) objects.push(object);
    if (object.isMesh) objects.castShadow = true;
  });
});
```

Screenshot for GLTF Demo:

Before Drag: https://prnt.sc/pu940g

After Drag: https://prnt.sc/pu93g3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use following code to drag multi mesh GLTF. It is Work for me.

 var dragobjects =[];
 //add following code in init function
 var gltfobject = addGLTFObjectIntoScene();
 scene.add(gltfobject);

dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(dragobjects, camera, renderer.domElement);
dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart, false);
dragControls.addEventListener('drag', onDrag , false);
dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', onDragEnd, false);
```

//end init function code
//add following function after or before init function

```
 function drawBox(objectwidth,objectheight,objectdepth){
 var geometry, material, box;
 geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(objectwidth,objectheight,objectdepth);
 material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00, transparent: true, opacity: 0,depthTest:false});
 box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 dragobjects.push(box);
 box.position.set(0, 0, 0);
 return box;
};  
function addGLTFObjectIntoScene(){ 
 group = new THREE.Group();
 var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
 loader.load( 'W1230/W1230.gltf', ( gltf ) => {
    mesh = gltf.scene;
    mesh.scale.set( 30, 30, 30);
    var gltfbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mesh );
    var objectwidth = Math.floor(gltfbox.getSize().x);
    var objectheight = Math.floor(gltfbox.getSize().y);
    var objectdepth = Math.floor(gltfbox.getSize().z);
    objectwidth = objectwidth + parseInt(2);
    objectheight = objectheight + parseInt(2);
    objectdepth  = objectdepth + parseInt(1);
    mesh.position.set(0, -objectheight/2, 0);
    box  = drawBox(objectwidth,objectheight,objectdepth); 
    group.add(box);
    group.name = "quadrant";
    console.log(mesh);
    box.add( mesh);
 });
 return group;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if you load a single `glTF` asset, the visual object can be composed of many individual 3D objects. Since `THREE.DragControls` works on object level, the mentioned result is the intended behavior.

The easiest way to fix this problem is to merge the single parts of your object in a content creation tool like Blender and then export a new `glTF`. Otherwise you have to merge the single meshes into a bigger one via `three.js`. Or you change `THREE.DragControls` so it is also able to select the group object based on its bounding box.

`three.js R113`